# what could be cause for CXErrorCodeRequestTransactionErrorUnentitled error in call kit?

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

i Am getting error while using call kit api CXStartCallAction(call: UUID(), handle: handle), call is not getting started, instead am getting  Error Domain=com.apple.CallKit.error.requesttransaction Code=1 "(null)"

Comment: I searched in Apple documentation and I found this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/callkit/cxerrorcoderequesttransactionerror/cxerrorcoderequesttransactionerrorunentitled Maybe you forgot do something in the app, because requesttransaction error code = 1 means that your app is unentitled for request transactions.

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

Ran into this problem just now.

It appears what resolved it for me was you need to add the following in you info.plist

- Required Background modes
- App provides Voice over IP services

[image]